# Nextflow Docker problem -- permission problem with Docker? Not able to run pomoxis container

Tags: docker, permissions, containers, nextflow

I'm new to nextflow and docker containers.
I am trying to denovo assemble some reads and map reads to a reference genome but keep getting the following error:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble$ nextflow pomoxis_map_assemble_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `pomoxis_map_assemble_nextflow.nf` [goofy_hoover] DSL1 - revision: 6e4be1e0bd
executor >  local (1)
executor >  local (1)
[cf/bc2b69] process > pomoxis (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `pomoxis (1)` terminated with an error exit status (127)

Command executed:

  mini_align -i output.fastq -r /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/ref/*.fasta -o results -p > output_test_final.fa

Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: mini_align: command not found

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/work/cf/bc2b696aea0863d76c2c9221315c39

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

The WARN is because I use a master config file for all of my .nf scripts.

Here is the logfile from the above error:

```
Oct.-12 10:33:04.759 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.Launcher - $> nextflow pomoxis_map_assemble_nextflow.nf
Oct.-12 10:33:04.822 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Oct.-12 10:33:04.837 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Found config local: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/nextflow.config
Oct.-12 10:33:04.838 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Parsing config file: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/nextflow.config
Oct.-12 10:33:04.856 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Applying config profile: `standard`
Oct.-12 10:33:05.414 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Applied DSL=1 by probing script field
Oct.-12 10:33:05.428 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Launching `pomoxis_map_assemble_nextflow.nf` [goofy_hoover] DSL1 - revision: 6e4be1e0bd
Oct.-12 10:33:05.439 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Setting up plugin manager > mode=prod; plugins-dir=/home/shaun/.nextflow/plugins; core-plugins: nf-amazon@1.7.2,nf-azure@0.13.2,nf-console@1.0.3,nf-ga4gh@1.0.3,nf-google@1.1.4,nf-sqldb@0.4.0,nf-tower@1.4.0
Oct.-12 10:33:05.440 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Plugins default=[]
Oct.-12 10:33:05.449 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Enabled plugins: []
Oct.-12 10:33:05.449 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Disabled plugins: []
Oct.-12 10:33:05.452 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager - PF4J version 3.4.1 in 'deployment' mode
Oct.-12 10:33:05.478 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.AbstractPluginManager - No plugins
Oct.-12 10:33:05.527 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session uuid: ddab5124-cc54-4c39-840d-6cc1bf664773
Oct.-12 10:33:05.527 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Run name: goofy_hoover
Oct.-12 10:33:05.527 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Executor pool size: 16
Oct.-12 10:33:05.547 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun - 
  Version: 22.04.5 build 5708
  Created: 15-07-2022 16:09 UTC (16-07-2022 01:39 ACDT)
  System: Linux 5.13.0-52-generic
  Runtime: Groovy 3.0.10 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8)
  Process: 665521@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation [127.0.1.1]
  CPUs: 16 - Mem: 62.5 GB (32.1 GB) - Swap: 2 GB (2 GB)
Oct.-12 10:33:05.564 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Work-dir: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/work [ext2/ext3]
Oct.-12 10:33:05.564 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Script base path does not exist or is not a directory: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/bin
Oct.-12 10:33:05.573 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - Extension executors providers=[]
Oct.-12 10:33:05.583 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Observer factory: DefaultObserverFactory
Oct.-12 10:33:05.605 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheFactory - Using Nextflow cache factory: nextflow.cache.DefaultCacheFactory
Oct.-12 10:33:05.613 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.CustomThreadPool - Creating default thread pool > poolSize: 17; maxThreads: 1000
Oct.-12 10:33:05.700 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session start invoked
Oct.-12 10:33:05.706 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.TraceFileObserver - Flow starting -- trace file: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/pipeline_trace.txt
Oct.-12 10:33:05.921 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Launching execution
Oct.-12 10:33:05.969 [PathVisitor-1] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/; pattern: *.fastq; options: [:]
Oct.-12 10:33:05.998 [PathVisitor-1] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/pomoxis_map_assemble/ref/; pattern: *.fasta; options: [:]
Oct.-12 10:33:06.048 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Oct.-12 10:33:06.048 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Oct.-12 10:33:06.052 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.Executor - [warm up] executor > local
Oct.-12 10:33:06.056 [main] DEBUG n.processor.LocalPollingMonitor - Creating local task monitor for executor 'local' > cpus=16; memory=62.5 GB; capacity=16; pollInterval=100ms; dumpInterval=5m
Oct.-12 10:33:06.121 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Workflow process names [dsl1]: pomoxis
Oct.-12 10:33:06.133 [main] WARN  nextflow.Session - There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
Oct.-12 10:33:06.134 [main] WARN  nextflow.Session - There's no process matching config selector: porechop
Oct.-12 10:33:06.135 [main] WARN  nextflow.Session - There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
Oct.-12 10:33:06.135 [main] WARN  nextflow.Session - There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
Oct.-12 10:33:06.135 [main] WARN  nextflow.Session - There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Oct.-12 10:33:06.135 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Await termination 
Oct.-12 10:33:06.135 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await
Oct.-12 10:33:06.344 [Task submitter] DEBUG nextflow.executor.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Oct.-12 10:33:06.349 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [cf/bc2b69] Submitted process > pomoxis (1)
Oct.-12 10:33:06.457 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 1; name: pomoxis (1); status: COMPLETED; exit: 127; error: -; workDir: /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/work/cf/bc2b696aea0863d76c2c9221315c39]
Oct.-12 10:33:06.491 [Task monitor] ERROR nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `pomoxis (1)` terminated with an error exit status (127)

Command executed:

  mini_align -i output.fastq -r /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/pomoxis_map_assemble/ref/*.fasta -o results -p > output_test_final.fa

Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: mini_align: command not found

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/work/cf/bc2b696aea0863d76c2c9221315c39

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
Oct.-12 10:33:06.499 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session aborted -- Cause: Process `pomoxis (1)` terminated with an error exit status (127)
Oct.-12 10:33:06.503 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all process finished
Oct.-12 10:33:06.520 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all barriers passed
Oct.-12 10:33:06.540 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.WorkflowStatsObserver - Workflow completed > WorkflowStats[succeededCount=0; failedCount=1; ignoredCount=0; cachedCount=0; pendingCount=0; submittedCount=0; runningCount=0; retriesCount=0; abortedCount=0; succeedDuration=0ms; failedDuration=1.2s; cachedDuration=0ms;loadCpus=0; loadMemory=0; peakRunning=1; peakCpus=16; peakMemory=60 GB; ]
Oct.-12 10:33:06.540 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.TraceFileObserver - Flow completing -- flushing trace file
Oct.-12 10:33:06.715 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheDB - Closing CacheDB done
Oct.-12 10:33:06.728 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Execution complete -- Goodbye
```

I have the same error when I try to use pomoxis to devno assemble the the reads:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble$ nextflow pomoxis_denovo_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `pomoxis_denovo_nextflow.nf` [intergalactic_sammet] DSL1 - revision: 1927bae9ab
executor >  local (1)
[fb/3868bc] process > pomoxis (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `pomoxis (1)` terminated with an error exit status (127)

Command executed:

  mini_assemble -i output.fastq -o results -p > output_test_final.fa

Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 2: mini_assemble: command not found

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_map_assemble/work/fb/3868bc97cabfa0d2934f4344c13c89

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

This this is the output for the `.command.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -ue
mini_assemble -i output.fastq -o results -p > output_test_final.fa
```

I have used the the flags for pomoxis from here --> https://nanoporetech.github.io/pomoxis/programs.html

Below are the two .nf files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

//data_location

params.outdir = './results'
params.in = "$PWD/*.fastq"
datasetA = Channel.fromPath(params.in)
params.ref = "$PWD/ref/*.fasta"
datasetB = Channel.fromPath(params.ref)


//map and assemble

process pomoxis {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path (c) from datasetA

    output:
    path "${c.baseName}_test_final.fa" into mapped_ch
  
    script:
    """
    mini_align -i $c -r $params.ref -o results -p > ${c.baseName}_test_final.fa 
    """
}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

//data_location

params.outdir = './results'
params.in = "$PWD/*.fastq"
dataset = Channel.fromPath(params.in)


//devno only

process pomoxis {
    
    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
        
    input:
    path (c) from dataset

    output:
    path "${c.baseName}_test_final.fa" into mapped_ch
  
    script:
    """
    mini_assemble -i $c -o results -p > ${c.baseName}_test_final.fa 
    """
}
```

Here is the config file, I have tried multiple docker containers from docker hub but I get the same error message.

```
//resume = true

process {
            cpus = 16
            accelerator = 'Quadro-RTX-5000'
              memory = 60. GB
}

trace {
        enabled = true
        file = 'pipeline_trace.txt'
        fields = 'task_id,hash,process,name,status,exit,module,container,cpus,time,disk,memory,attempt,submit,start,complete,duration,realtime,queue,%cpu,%mem'
}

docker {
            enabled = true
            temp = 'auto'
            runOption = '--user root' 
}

params {
            nt_db_20221011 = '/home/shaun/blast/nt_db_20221011/nt'
}

process {
            withName:fastqc      {container = 'staphb/fastqc:latest'                                               }
            withName:porechop    {container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/porechop:0.2.3_seqan2.1.1--py36h2d50403_3'    }
            withName:bioawk      {container = 'wslhbio/bioawk:1.0-wslh-signed'                                     }
            withName:fastqconvert{container = 'staphb/seqtk:1.3'                                                   }
            withName:blast_raw   {container = 'staphb/blast:2.13.0'                                                }
            withname:pomoxis    {container = 'dpirdmk/pomoxis:0.1.11'                          }
}
```

---

**Update:**

After correcting the syntax error, I changed the container as suggested and added the -h function to the script section.
The following is the output from this:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_align$ nextflow pomoxis_align_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `pomoxis_align_nextflow.nf` [voluminous_solvay] DSL1 - revision: 4dca1d1d46
executor >  local (1)
[55/4dad0b] process > pomoxis (1) [  0%] 0 of 1
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output` expected by process `pomoxis (1)`

Command executed:

  mini_align -h

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)
executor >  local (1)
[55/4dad0b] process > pomoxis (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output` expected by process `pomoxis (1)`

Command executed:

  mini_align -h

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  mini_align [-h] -r <reference> -i <fastq>

  Align fastq/a formatted reads to a genome using minimap2.

      -h  show this help text.
      -r  reference, should be a fasta file. If correspondng minimap indices
          do not exist they will be created. (required).
      -i  fastq/a input reads (required).
      -I  split index every ~NUM input bases (default: 16G, this is larger
          than the usual minimap2 default).
      -d  set the minimap2 preset, e.g. map-ont, asm5, asm10, asm20 [default: map-ont]
      -f  force recreation of index file.
      -a  aggressively extend gaps (sets -A1 -B2 -O2 -E1 for minimap2).
      -P  filter to only primary alignments (i.e. run samtools view -F 2308).
          Deprecated: this filter is now default and can be disabled with -A.
      -y  filter to primary and supplementary alignments (i.e. run samtools view -F 260)
      -A  do not filter alignments, output all.
      -n  sort bam by read name.
      -c  chunk size. Input reads/contigs will be broken into chunks
          prior to alignment.
      -t  alignment threads (default: 1).
      -p  output file prefix (default: reads).
      -m  fill MD tag.
      -s  fill cs(=long) tag.
      -X  only create reference index files.
      -x  log all commands before running.
      -M  match score
      -S  mismatch score
      -O  open gap penalty
      -E  extend gap penalty.

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_align/work/55/4dad0b1df7105e31362f58b0c67f1f

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`
```

Athough there is an error, I'm assuming this worked as I can see the help menu?

I then added flags to the script section of the .nf as per the Pomoxis website.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

//data_location

params.outdir = './results'
params.in = "$PWD/*.fastq"
datasetA = Channel.fromPath(params.in)
params.ref = "$PWD/SLCMV.fasta"
datasetB = Channel.fromPath(params.ref)


//map and assemble; input fastq only
//output; pomoxis is very particular about names, minimap can out put 
//.sam or .paf 

process pomoxis {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
        
    input:
    path (c) from datasetA
    path (d) from datasetB

    output:
    path "${c.simpleName}" into mapped_ch
  
    script:
    """
    mini_align -r $d -i $c -p ${c.simpleName}
    """
}
```

The results are below:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_align$ nextflow pomoxis_align_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `pomoxis_align_nextflow.nf` [determined_bassi] DSL1 - revision: 1ad3e75c1b
executor >  local (1)
[50/860f9f] process > pomoxis (1) [  0%] 0 of 1
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output` expected by process `pomoxis (1)`
executor >  local (1)
[50/860f9f] process > pomoxis (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqc
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: porechop
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: bioawk
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: fastqconvert
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: blast_raw
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output` expected by process `pomoxis (1)`

Command executed:

  mini_align -r SLCMV.fasta -i output.fastq -p output

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  Creating fai index file SLCMV.fasta.fai
  Creating mmi index file SLCMV.fasta.map-ont.mmi
  [M::mm_idx_gen::0.003*2.10] collected minimizers
  [M::mm_idx_gen::0.005*2.42] sorted minimizers
  [M::main::0.009*1.77] loaded/built the index for 1 target sequence(s)
  [M::mm_idx_stat] kmer size: 15; skip: 10; is_hpc: 0; #seq: 1
  [M::mm_idx_stat::0.009*1.74] distinct minimizers: 522 (100.00% are singletons); average occurrences: 1.000; average spacing: 5.282; total length: 2757
  [M::main] Version: 2.24-r1122
  [M::main] CMD: minimap2 -I 16G -x map-ont -d SLCMV.fasta.map-ont.mmi SLCMV.fasta
  [M::main] Real time: 0.010 sec; CPU: 0.017 sec; Peak RSS: 0.003 GB
  [M::main::0.005*1.39] loaded/built the index for 1 target sequence(s)
  [M::mm_mapopt_update::0.005*1.37] mid_occ = 10
  [M::mm_idx_stat] kmer size: 15; skip: 10; is_hpc: 0; #seq: 1
  [M::mm_idx_stat::0.005*1.35] distinct minimizers: 522 (100.00% are singletons); average occurrences: 1.000; average spacing: 5.282; total length: 2757
  [M::worker_pipeline::9.159*1.00] mapped 87369 sequences
  [M::main] Version: 2.24-r1122
  [M::main] CMD: minimap2 -x map-ont --secondary=no -L -t 1 -a SLCMV.fasta.map-ont.mmi output.fastq
  [M::main] Real time: 9.182 sec; CPU: 9.145 sec; Peak RSS: 0.299 GB

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_align/work/50/860f9ffe37f7a17a4d5e216f67b512

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I've tried changing the output name but this hasnt help.

interestingly, when I run mini_assemble .nf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

//data_location

params.outdir = './results'
params.in = "$PWD/*.fastq"
dataset = Channel.fromPath(params.in)

//devno only; input is fastq
//output; pomoxis is very particular about names, the name that it out puts is
//prefix_test_final.fa where prefic can be anything and it will add _test_final.fa
//to the end of the file


process pomoxis {

    tag "$c"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode:'copy'
        
    input:
    path (c) from dataset

    output:
    path ("${c.simpleName}_test_final.fa") into mapped_ch
  
    script:
    """
    mini_assemble -i $c -p ${c.simpleName}
    """ 
}
```

I get the following error:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/WA_MomicaKehoe/Asad/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_assemble$ nextflow pomoxis_assemble_nextflow.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.5
Launching `pomoxis_assemble_nextflow.nf` [intergalactic_fermi] DSL1 - revision: ce7a466307
executor >  local (1)
[04/28f5e6] process > pomoxis (output.fastq) [  0%] 0 of 1


Error executing process > 'pomoxis (output.fastq)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output_test_final.fa` expected by process `pomoxis (output.fastq)`

Command executed:

  mini_assemble -i output.fastq -p output

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  Copying FASTX input to workspace: output.fastq > assm/output.fa.gz
  Skipped adapter trimming.
  Skipped pre-assembly correction.
  Overlapping reads...
  Assembling graph...
  Running racon read shuffle 1...
  Running round 1 consensus...
  Running round 2 consensus...
  Running round 3 consensus...
  Running round 4 consensus...
  Waiting for cleanup.
  Final assembly written to assm/output_final.fa. Have a nice day.

Command error:
  [M::mm_idx_stat::0.065*1.04] distinct minimizers: 69519 (92.83% are singletons); average occurrences: 1.101; average spacing: 5.337; total length: 408518
  [M::worker_pipeline::9.872*0.97] mapped 87369 sequences
  [M::main] Version: 2.24-r1122
  [M::main] CMD: minimap2 -L -K 500M -t 1 racon_1_3.fa.gz output.fa.gz
  [M::main] Real time: 9.880 sec; CPU: 9.620 sec; Peak RSS: 0.165 GB
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded target sequences 0.011974 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded sequences 2.047803 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded overlaps 0.106485 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=>                  ] 1.252726 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==>                 ] 1.827141 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===>                ] 2.413558 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [====>               ] 2.974846 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=====>              ] 3.609222 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [======>             ] 4.263570 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=======>            ] 4.934294 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [========>           ] 5.554714 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=========>          ] 6.164404 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==========>         ] 6.746845 s
executor >  local (1)
[04/28f5e6] process > pomoxis (output.fastq) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
Error executing process > 'pomoxis (output.fastq)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `output_test_final.fa` expected by process `pomoxis (output.fastq)`

Command executed:

  mini_assemble -i output.fastq -p output

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  Copying FASTX input to workspace: output.fastq > assm/output.fa.gz
  Skipped adapter trimming.
  Skipped pre-assembly correction.
  Overlapping reads...
  Assembling graph...
  Running racon read shuffle 1...
  Running round 1 consensus...
  Running round 2 consensus...
  Running round 3 consensus...
  Running round 4 consensus...
  Waiting for cleanup.
  Final assembly written to assm/output_final.fa. Have a nice day.

Command error:
  [M::mm_idx_stat::0.065*1.04] distinct minimizers: 69519 (92.83% are singletons); average occurrences: 1.101; average spacing: 5.337; total length: 408518
  [M::worker_pipeline::9.872*0.97] mapped 87369 sequences
  [M::main] Version: 2.24-r1122
  [M::main] CMD: minimap2 -L -K 500M -t 1 racon_1_3.fa.gz output.fa.gz
  [M::main] Real time: 9.880 sec; CPU: 9.620 sec; Peak RSS: 0.165 GB
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded target sequences 0.011974 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded sequences 2.047803 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] loaded overlaps 0.106485 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=>                  ] 1.252726 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==>                 ] 1.827141 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===>                ] 2.413558 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [====>               ] 2.974846 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=====>              ] 3.609222 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [======>             ] 4.263570 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=======>            ] 4.934294 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [========>           ] 5.554714 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=========>          ] 6.164404 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==========>         ] 6.746845 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===========>        ] 7.282895 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [============>       ] 7.878856 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=============>      ] 8.459672 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==============>     ] 8.984196 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===============>    ] 9.558089 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [================>   ] 10.072586 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [=================>  ] 10.648603 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [==================> ] 11.220553 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [===================>] 11.753881 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] aligning overlaps [====================] 12.364460 s
  [racon::Polisher::initialize] transformed data into windows 0.018851 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=>                  ] 0.515508 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [==>                 ] 1.077083 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [===>                ] 1.561330 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [====>               ] 1.967063 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=====>              ] 2.574379 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [======>             ] 3.037187 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=======>            ] 3.740370 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [========>           ] 20.112573 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=========>          ] 46.718507 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [==========>         ] 48.913841 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [===========>        ] 52.859126 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [============>       ] 57.495382 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=============>      ] 74.111321 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [==============>     ] 79.382051 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [===============>    ] 113.129291 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [================>   ] 115.971094 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [=================>  ] 123.322513 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [==================> ] 128.155934 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [===================>] 130.509134 s
  [racon::Polisher::polish] generating consensus [====================] 131.095442 s
  [racon::Polisher::] total = 145.794273 s

Work dir:
  /home/shaun/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/WA_MomicaKehoe/Asad/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_assemble/work/04/28f5e6eed13d3fc986739e287594d9

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

However, the file that I need is in:

```
shaun@shaun-HP-Z6-G4-Workstation:~/nextflow_pipelines/pipelines/nf_pipeline/pomoxis_assemble/work/04/28f5e6eed13d3fc986739e287594d9/assm$ cat output_final.fa
```

When I cat this file I can see that there are contig in the file as expected.

I can see that pomoxis is expecting `output_test_final.fa`, which is indeed in the work dir, but pomoxis cant see it or use it?

Do you have any suggestions on why these errors are occuring?
I appreciate your time.

Comment: I tried appending the contents of the deleted reply, but hit the 30000 character limit. I removed part about the Docker installation/configuration to make it fit. Please consider revising your question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Command error:
>   .command.sh: line 2: mini_assemble: command not found
> ```

You will get this error when you try to run a command outside of a container and the executable does not exist in your `$PATH`. Usually we see this when we forget to add `docker.enabled = true` (or `singularity.enabled = true` if using Singualarity) to our [nextflow.config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#configuration-file). However, in this case it's just caused by a typo in your config file. The `withName` [config selector](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html?#process-selectors) must be camel case. You will also get a 'command not found' error using the chosen container. If we instead use the [pomoxis biocontainer](https://biocontainers.pro/tools/pomoxis), we get the expected result. For example:

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
docker {
    enabled = true
}

process {

    withName: pomoxis {
        container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/pomoxis:0.3.10--pyhdfd78af_0'
    }
}
```

Contents of `map_and_assembly.nf`:

```
process pomoxis {

    """
    mini_align -h
    """
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run map_and_assembly.nf -dsl1
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.4
Launching `map_and_assembly.nf` [loving_thompson] DSL1 - revision: 6efbc53bf8
executor >  local (1)
[22/23c938] process > pomoxis [100%] 1 of 1 ✔

Completed at: 13-Oct-2022 01:05:27
Duration    : 2m 46s
CPU hours   : (a few seconds)
Succeeded   : 1
```

```
$ cat work/22/23c938ca9312037ee10087ba5d48a2/.command.err 
Unable to find image 'quay.io/biocontainers/pomoxis:0.3.10--pyhdfd78af_0' locally
0.3.10--pyhdfd78af_0: Pulling from biocontainers/pomoxis
c1a16a04cedd: Already exists
4ca545ee6d5d: Already exists
af0d0c971daf: Pulling fs layer
af0d0c971daf: Verifying Checksum
af0d0c971daf: Download complete
af0d0c971daf: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b42d95b742be3dc8333f57892c4aa2cc5cd739e796b33c7f310696856dcdea4d
Status: Downloaded newer image for quay.io/biocontainers/pomoxis:0.3.10--pyhdfd78af_0
mini_align [-h] -r <reference> -i <fastq>

Align fastq/a formatted reads to a genome using minimap2.

    -h  show this help text.
    -r  reference, should be a fasta file. If correspondng minimap indices
        do not exist they will be created. (required).
    -i  fastq/a input reads (required).
    -I  split index every ~NUM input bases (default: 16G, this is larger
        than the usual minimap2 default).
    -d  set the minimap2 preset, e.g. map-ont, asm5, asm10, asm20 [default: map-ont]
    -f  force recreation of index file.
    -a  aggressively extend gaps (sets -A1 -B2 -O2 -E1 for minimap2).
    -P  filter to only primary alignments (i.e. run samtools view -F 2308).
        Deprecated: this filter is now default and can be disabled with -A.
    -y  filter to primary and supplementary alignments (i.e. run samtools view -F 260)
    -A  do not filter alignments, output all.
    -n  sort bam by read name.
    -c  chunk size. Input reads/contigs will be broken into chunks
        prior to alignment.
    -t  alignment threads (default: 1).
    -p  output file prefix (default: reads).
    -m  fill MD tag.
    -s  fill cs(=long) tag.
    -X  only create reference index files.
    -x  log all commands before running.
    -M  match score 
    -S  mismatch score
    -O  open gap penalty
    -E  extend gap penalty.
```

The problem with using the `dpirdmk/pomoxis:0.1.11` container is that it specifies an alternate entrypoint which makes it difficult to use out of the box without either modifying the command to be run or by supplying some additional Docker configuration:

```
$ docker run --rm dpirdmk/pomoxis:0.1.11 bash -c 'cat /init.sh'
#!/bin/bash
. /apps/pomoxis/venv/bin/activate
exec "$@"
```

---

**Reply to follow up questions:**

You receive the `` Missing output file(s) `output` expected by process `` error when the command completes successfully (i.e. exit status zero) but Nextflow (not `pomoxis`) couldn't find one or more output file(s) in the working directory as specified in the [output](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) declaration. I think what you want is the following. I've taken the liberty of renaming some of the variables to make things a little more clear. The code below is of course untested:

```
params.outdir = './results'

params.ref_fasta = "SLCMV.fasta"
params.reads = "*.fastq"

reads = Channel.fromPath( params.reads )
ref_fasta = file( params.ref_fasta )


process mini_align {

    tag { fastq.name }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/mini_align", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path fastq from reads
    path ref_fasta

    output:
    path "${fastq.simpleName}.bam{,.bai}" into mapped_ch

    script:
    """
    mini_align \\
        -r "${ref_fasta}" \\
        -i "${fastq}" \\
        -p "${fastq.simpleName}"
    """
}
```

```
params.outdir = './results'

params.reads = "*.fastq"

reads = Channel.fromPath( params.reads )


process mini_assemble {

    tag { fastq.name }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/mini_assemble", mode:'copy'

    input:
    path fastq from reads

    output:
    path "assm/${fastq.simpleName}_final.fa" into mapped_ch

    script:
    """
    mini_assemble \\
        -i "${fastq}" \\
        -p "${fastq.simpleName}"
    """
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've followed your suggestions above. These fixed the initial errors, though there are a few more, if you have some time. I've added them as an answer.

Comment: @naqs Please see my updated answer above. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for that, subtle but important changes! I've followed the above scripts and it's now working for me. Still reading the docs trying to wrap my head around this stuff. I appreciate your time and effort in helping me out.